# Comparing 2 dimensional Array to 1 dimensional Array in java

Tags: java, arrays

The 1st array's elements are arrays, so the 1st array contains four element-arrays.

The 2nd array is a one dimensional array.

My task is to  test if each string of an element-array is present in the 2nd array. If present, the value should be printed.

```
String[][] arr1 = {
    {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, 
    {"a", "d", "f"}, 
    {"d", "a", "b"}, 
    {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
};
String[] arr2 = {"a","b", "d","f"};
```

The output should be:

```
a d f
d a b
```

How can I process these arrays for the needed output?

Comment: You can flatten arr1 and create a Set of elements in arr1 and then find if elements from arr2 exist in that set. try it yourself first and let me know if you need the code

Comment: @Amit you can also do it with a couple of nested for loops.

Comment: What you're asking and your sample output don't make sense together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] arr1 = {
        {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, 
        {"a", "d", "f"}, 
        {"d", "a", "b"}, 
        {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    };
    String[] arr2 = {"a", "b", "d", "f"};

    for (String[] letters : arr1) {
        boolean containsAll = true;
        for (String letter : letters) {
            boolean match = false;
            for (String s : arr2) {
                if (letter.equals(s))
                    match = true;
            }
            if(!match){
                containsAll = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(containsAll){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
        }
    }

}
```

Out is:

```
[a, d, f]
[d, a, b]
```

Comment: "Required output of it sould be:

a d f
d a b"

Comment: It needs to print the array of which all the elements are contained in arr2.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for this very concise code and giving 100% required output.